# what does "->" mean in "rect(Surface, color, Rect, width=0) -> Rect"

Tags: python

this is a part from the document of pygame, I don't know what does "->" mean.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->` generally means "returns". In your case, your `rect()` function returns a `Rect` instance.